# PHP function not running

Tags: php, arrays, function

My page grabs some records from a mssql DB, reads them into an array called `$rows`, with 3 columns:

> ComputerName, Room, time_in_days

From `$rows` a second array is created (called `$graph`) with two columns, with the key being time_in_days from `$rows`, and the value column being a count of how often `time_in_days` occurred in the first array. The `$graph` array is used to create a number of HTML divs to give the impression of a graph.

I then want to be able to click on each individual div and using the $key value from the $graphs array, want to look up the rest of the information associated with all records in $rows where `$graph[$key]`  matches `$rows['time_in_days']` and display those records on the page.

But I have got stuck! I don't know where to put the function, the if statement(see code below) and at the moment, it doesn't even seem to be running the function. I don't even think I have the function code right. So if you could help with any of that I will very much appreciate it!

This is the code where the divs/graph is created:

```
  foreach($graph as $key => $value){
        $width = $value * $factor;
        $page .= '<div style="width:40px;display:inline-block;">'.$key.'</div><a href="index.php?barclick=true"><div class="bar '.$key.'" style="width:'.$width.'px;"></div></a><div style="display:inline-block;margin-left:2px;">'.$value.'</div><br/>';  
    }
```

This is the function so far:

```
function SearchDays($key, $page, $rows) {
    $computers = array(); 
    foreach ($rows as $arr){
        if ($key == $arr["time_in_days"]){
            $computerName = $arr["ComputerName"];
            $computers[$computerName] = $arr;
        }
    }
    $page .= '<p>computers array from function SearchDays(): <pre>'.print_r($computers,true).'</pre></p>';
    return; 
}
```

And this is the if statement that makes the if statement that should run the function:

```
if (isset($_GET['barclick'])){
        SearchDays($key, $page, $rows);
    }
```

`$page` is just a variable that holds everything that is printed out onto the HTML page. The page itself can be seen here: [cems.uwe.ac.uk/~s3-gupta/histogram/index.php](http://cems.uwe.ac.uk/~s3-gupta/histogram/index.php). The whole page code can be got here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h2q7x9xxtjbktx9/index.php

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if you need me to clarify things. I try and be as clear as possible on here, but usually don't manage it, so let me know if you need more.

Comment: your function only ends with return; should it return some data instead ?

Comment: if you're trying to concatenate to $page and keep the information, pass $page by reference. add an ampersand before it in the function parameters ie... SearchDay($key, &$page, $rows)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I don't know whether it should or not, that's part of my problem.

Comment: @Bryan Thanks! Now it's returning data which is something. I didn't realise that an ampersand was necessary. Now I just need to work out where to put the function and the if statement so it gets the correct $key value.